# Slow search in text on azure sql

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a product table with a description column. The table contains ~250 000 products. (It will be more in the future)

When i run this:

```
select id, title, link from products where description like '%red jeans%'
```

it takes ~4 minutes to get the result. This table only contains links to other websites so the table don't have any relations to the rest of the database.

What can we do to speed up the search? Use other azure feature? Create a new table with search words and join them with the products? Whats best to do?

(What we do is to download a rss feed of products, and add them to the table in the database. And then we let our users search for products)

**UPDATE:**

If we add all products to Redis, what is the best way to do this?

I have this:

```
static readonly ConnectionMultiplexer CacheConnection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("contoso5.redis.cache.windows.net,ssl=true,password=...");
private static void SaveToRedis(List<Product> products)
{
    var Cache = CacheConnection.GetDatabase();
}

private static List<Product> SearchProducts(string words)
{
    var Cache = CacheConnection.GetDatabase();
}
```

The Product object contains for example ProductNr, Title, Description, Price ...
In SearchProducts i will search in the description after products with the words.

Comment: I guess you can scale up your db with DTUs and can compare, and if possible try to use redis cache, its really fast compared to Azure SQL and is really easy to implement.

Comment: Thanx.I think it will be to expensive to scale up the db. If we use redis, what is the best way to do this?  First save all products to the database. Then save it to the redis cache. Should we save a List of products to the cache? Or what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Ya its easy to use with .NET object you can check on web beside They call it cache-aside pattern as per documentation which seems logical too, every new select is from database but is stored on Azure cache with expiration duration so next time the fetch is from Azure Cache coz its there due to persistance

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I updated my question with some code :)
What is the best way to go now? :)

Comment: Please refer to cache aside pattern, that would be more useful I guess

Comment: Thanx. I found Lucene.Net and it was perfect for speed up the search =)

Comment: I think you must check Solr based on Lucene with easy implementation